# DOM XSS in Jquery show() function

Tags: jquery, xss

I am showing a div in Jquery using

```
function{
....
$('#' + item + '-add').show(); 
...
}
```

The id of the div is dynamically selected based on user choices. Our code scanner keeps marking above line as DOM based XSS.

*item* is fetched from a hidden field on page

```
item  = $('.classname').val();

<input type="hidden" value="{{unit}}" class="classname">
```

I have tried multiple payloads, but I am unable to execute an alert. is this a valid DOM vulnerability and what payload would I need to pass in *item* to exploit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is flagged is not `show()`. It's because `$('#' + item + '-add')` appends user input in a jquery selector. As jquery can create html tags like that, it very much rings the xss bell. A code scanner cannot really tell what's happening in the background, so it's flagging it for you to check.

In your case this user input is directly preceded with a `#` as the first character of the selector. Even better if there is no way for a user to set the value of {{unit}}, it's unclear where that comes from, but it doesn't matter much anyway.

I think this is not exploitable ("mitigated by design" in Veracode for example), but depending on your percieved risks and threats, you might still want to change it to something more robust (refactor the code to not include user input in jquery selectors - which might already be the case if {{unit}} is not user input).